# Ubuntu on AMD Laptop: cannot boot

Tags: boot, system-installation, amd-processor, lockup

Specs of my laptop are: processor: AMD E1-2500 graphics: Radeon HD 8240. Whenever I try to install linux in it, it gives some errors. In ubuntu's case, it does not boot, and the screen just goes black(when I change to UEFI boot, it goes white). In opensuse's case, it freezed but I was able to look at terminal output and it said that it detected some **CPU lockup**. I have had Fedora on the same laptop for some time until an update messed it up and it again gave **CPU lockup** error, so I am guessing Ubuntu has the same problem. My guess is that new kernels have that issue with my processor, since I don't think I have hardware problems, as I run windows without any issue(also I was running fedora before some update).

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You can refer to the following link:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: @user223882 Thanks, it works for now. I am using LTS, can you tell me if it updates the kernel or not? I am afraid that a kernel update will mess things up.